# SQL: select records based on certain criteria, merging records that are duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL statement that will derive a list of rows that are unique.

Given this set of data, I want the result to remove duplicate rows where duplicate is defined as Column1 being identical and column 2 and 3 are empty

```
Things:

ID    Column1    Column2        Column3
1        a          z              4
2        b          y              7
3        b          m              9
4        a                        
5        a 
6        a          z              4
```

Expected Result:

```
a, z, 4
b, y, 7
b, m, 9
a,  , 
a, z, 4
```

Note that a, z, 4 appears twice in the result and this is correct.  Rows only get merged when Column1 is the same and Column2 and Column3 are empty.

How would I construct a query to get this result?

Answer (score 1):

Using the unique (and therefore non-group-able) id when it's non-null, and a group-able null when it's null should work.

```
select Column1, Column2, Column3
from Things
group by case when Column1 is null then null else ID end,
    case when Column2 is null then null else ID end,
    case when Column3 is null then null else ID end
```

Comment: Sorry, don't think this will work.  Note that I only want to merge rows when Col2 and Col3 are empty.  Rows 1 and 6 should not be merged, as would occur in your example using group by.

Comment: @dtburgess - I updated the sql, which should now keep non-null duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work in mysql if the empty columns contain nulls. The first part of the query returns all of the 'extra' rows, but only those extras where the columns are not null (this is the way value comparison works in mysql, at least). The second (distinct) query returns one of everything, including the null values. The net result is exactly what you were asking for:

```
select a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3
    from Things a, Things b 
    where a.Column1 = b.Column1 
    and a.Column2 = b.Column2 
    and a.Column3 = b.Column3 
    and a.ID < b.ID 
union all 
    select distinct Column1, Column2, Column3 from Things;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
    Column1
  , Column2
  , Column3
FROM MyTable
```

should do, as would:

```
SELECT 
  Column1
, Column2
, Column3
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Sorry, don't think this will work.  Note that I only want to merge rows when Col2 and Col3 are empty.  Rows 1 and 6 should not be merged, as would occur in your example using distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do union as

```
select column1,column2,column3  from Things 
union  
select column1,column2,column3 from Things 
where col2 = '' and col3 = '' ;
```