# SQL: handling mismatch of columns for INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow up question related to this post:
[SQL: select records based on certain criteria, merging records that are duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854741/sql-select-records-based-on-certain-criteria-merging-records-that-are-duplicat)

- The goal of this query is to: gather USE contact records from the
  child records of the parent
- remove duplicates as defined by an identical id_val__type and id_emp 
  (hence the GROUP BY id_val__type, id_emp ). MIN ( id_usg ) ensures
  that that field can be excluded from the GROUP BY
- create new USE contact records for the parent record from the result

This works great to find and create records:

```
INSERT INTO USE ( id_val__type, id_emp, sql_temp, id_usg )
SELECT id_val__type, id_emp, MIN ( id_usg ), $idParent
FROM USE
WHERE id_usg IN ( 'childID1','childID2','childID3' ) 
GROUP BY id_val__type, id_emp
```

Note however that I have created a throwaway column sql_temp.  This was necessary so that there were an equal number of columns in the SELECT result as there are columns to be INSERTed INTO. sql_temp is simply there as a place to throw the unnecessary id_usg column data.

Problem to solve: How, in a single query, would I meet both requirements:

- Remove duplicates by grouping on id_val_type, id_emp (or some other method)
- Provide for the correct number of columns to INSERT INTO

That said, I see two solutions:

1. Use CREATE and DROP to temporarily create the field
2. OR - Refactor the SQL so that the id_usg result column does not gum up the INSERT INTO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
INSERT INTO USE ( id_val__type, id_emp,  id_usg )
    SELECT id_val__type, id_emp, $idParent
    FROM USE
    WHERE id_usg IN ('childID1', 'childID2', 'childID3') 
    GROUP BY id_val__type, id_emp;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Looks to me like this is correct, although if I am not including $idParent in GROUP BY, then I need to wrap it in a aggragate function like MIN ( $idparent ).  Correct?  All values for $idParent are the same.